# Complement in Conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$P(X_1=A, X_2=B, X_3=C|X_4 =E)=P(X_1=A|X_4 =E)P(X_2=B|X_4 =E,X_1=A)P(X_3=C|X_4=E,X_1=A,X_2=B)$

I am wondering, is there a formula for calcuting

$P(X_1\neq A, X_2 \neq B, X_3 \neq C| X_4=E)?$
Can I basically just replace "Right-Hand-Side" in the first equation with $X_1 \neq A$, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

$$\begin{align}
& \mathsf P(X_1 {\ne} A, X_2{\ne}B, X_3{\ne}C\mid X_4 {=}E) 
\\[0.5ex] & \quad =\mathsf P(X_1{\ne}A\mid X_4{=}E)\,\mathsf P(X_2{\ne}B\mid X_4{=}E,X_1{\ne}A)\,\mathsf P(X_3{\ne}C\mid X_4{=}E,X_1{\ne}A,X_2{\ne}B)\end{align}$$

That is, presuming that you know these conditional probabilities.